# HDMI Chroma Key Programming

Tags: c#, video-streaming, screen-capture, hdmi, chromakey

I googled so much but I did not find any solution.

I created a app with c# wpf. It is creating UI from first desktop's dashboard in second desktop. UI's background is green and it contains some different graphics for example orange. I would like change green color to alpha (transparent) and push to HDMI in real time for showing in out source devices like TV or Monitor

I mean I would like apply Chroma Key for HDMI. is it possible or not?

Comment: Which graphics API are you using?

Comment: Hello @Brad I am not using any graphics API. If below logic is possible, can you suggest tool or API?